# How to use c# for automation?

Tags: c#, automation

Is there anyway to do automatic actions like clicking menus and pasting a text in a particular area on an application using c#?

I know about auto it.. But our customer don't want it..

Comment: Is it a web application?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615105/getting-text-entered-in-textbox-of-other-applications-using-c-sharp - this group of APIs will also help with clicking objects as well.

Comment: @SachinNambiar no its not