# Read/parse application content

Tags: powershell, parsing

I wanted to see the possibility of getting the text displayed by a certain installed application and running on windows in a certain open window.

Is there a generic way to access the contents of an open window?

Thanks for all your help

Comment: You need to find control's handle. This is not a trivial task, as illustriated by [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1873404) quick [results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17615105).

Comment: Especially bearing in mind the comment above from @vonPryz, is this really a PowerShell question?